# SimpleDate format is not converting time to IST

Tags: java, timezone

I am trying to get time (HH:MM) from below code in IST format but it still display UTC date, time.
Please help.

```java
public static void main (String args[]) throws ParseException {
    String date = "2021-07-05T14:17:00.000Z";
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimeZone timeZone = now.getTimeZone();
    String timezoneID = timeZone.getID();
    // Convert to System format from UTC
    SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    Date actualDate = format1.parse(date);
    format1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezoneID));
    String date1 = format1.format(actualDate);
    String time = date1.substring(11, 16);
    String timezoneValue = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezoneID).getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT);
    String finalTime = time + " " + timezoneValue;
    System.out.print(finalTime);
}
```

Comment: I am nota able to see where you are passing IST timezone id?

Comment: format1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezoneID)); here i am doing it

Comment: The output is "14:17 MEZ" what did you expect?

Comment: could you please pass it by yourself instead of using the default timezone? I think it's related to the system.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I am expecting 19:47 since UTC to IST difference is 5.30 hrs

Comment: I can't see where you set IST timezone

Comment: in this line I set it, format1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezoneID));

Comment: Remove all uses of `timezoneID`.  You already have a TimeZone instance.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`, `TimeZone`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, `SimpleDateFormat` in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `Instant`, `ZoneId` and `ZonedDateTime`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are parsing the date using your default TimeZone, not UTC.

You never called `format1.setTimeZone` *before* parsing.  A DateFormat uses the default timezone unless you set it to something else.

Let’s look at each line of your code:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone timeZone = now.getTimeZone();
```

That is getting the default TimeZone.  You don’t need a Calendar object for that;  just call [TimeZone.getDefault()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()).

```
String timezoneID = timeZone.getID();
```

There is no reason to call that.  You already have a TimeZone object.  Converting it to a string ID and back to a TimeZone is a pointless round-trip operation.  So, you should remove all uses of `timezoneID`.

```
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
```

That is the problem.  The DateFormat doesn’t treat the `'Z'` as anything special;   it’s just a literal character which the DateFormat knows not to parse.

You need to actually tell the DateFormat that it’s parsing a UTC time:

```
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");

TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
format1.setTimeZone(utc);

Date actualDate = format1.parse(date);
```

Instead of cutting out pieces of a formatted string, make a new DateFormat that does exactly what you want:

```
DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm z");
String finalTime = timeFormat.format(actualDate);
```

Since a SimpleDateFormat always uses the default TimeZone when it is created, there is no need to call this format object’s setTimeZone method.

I should mention that the java.time and java.time.format packages are much better for working with dates and times:

```
String date = "2021-07-05T14:17:00.000Z";
Instant instant = Instant.parse(date);

ZonedDateTime utcDateTime = instant.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
ZonedDateTime istDateTime =
    utcDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault());

String finalTime = String.format("%tR %<tZ", istDateTime);
// Or:
// String finalTime = istDateTime.toLocalTime() + " "
//    + itsDateTime.getZone().getDisplayName(
//        TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
```

Answer (score 3):

### java.time

I strongly recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. Then your task becomes pretty simple. Rather than a formatter for your input format I want to define a formatter for your desired time format:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter TIME_FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm zzz", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Now the operation goes in these few lines:

```
    String date = "2021-07-05T14:17:00.000Z";
    
    String finalTime = Instant.parse(date)
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .format(TIME_FORMATTER);
    
    System.out.println(finalTime);
```

Output when I ran in Europe/Dublin time zone:

> 15:17 IST

Here IST is for Irish Summer Time. IST has several meanings, and I wasn’t sure which one you intended. Also many of the other popular time zone abbreviations are ambiguous. IST may also mean Israel Standard Time, but not here, since Israel uses Israel Daylight Time or IDT at this time of year. One other interpretation is India Standard Time used in India and Sri Lanka, So let’s try running the code in Asia/Kolkata time zone.

> 19:47 IST

I am exploiting the fact that your string is in ISO 8601 format, the format that the classes of java.time parse and also print as their default, that is, without any specified formatter.

### What went wrong in your code?

Your bug is here:

```
    SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
```

You must never hardcode `Z` as a literal in your format pattern, which is what you are doing when enclosing it in single quotes. The `Z` is a UTC offset and needs to be parsed as such so that Java knows that your date and time are in UTC (which is what `Z` means). When you hardcode the `Z`, `SimpleDateFormat` understands the date and time to be in the default time zone of the JVM. So when afterward you try to convert into that time zone, the time of day is not changed. You’re converting into the time zone you already had. It’s a no-op.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [Time Zone Abbreviations – Worldwide List](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/)

Answer (score 0):

`format1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));`

is what you need since the 3-letter zone names are really deprecated. Plus:

`String timezoneValue = format1.getTimeZone().getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT);`

Comment: Above code works fine if date is in yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX format

Comment: I still get 14:17 ..its not converting to IST

Comment: 18:47 IST is what I get

Comment: I am not getting it after replacing format1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata")); line. Please advice

Comment: DId you replace the other line I mentioned too?

Comment: Yes I did..i get same time no difference

Answer (score 0):

The method `Calendar.getInstance()` gets a calendar using the default time zone and locale - UTC±00:00.

Use `"IST"` instead of `timeZone.getID()`.

Exemple:

```
String date="2021-07-05T14:17:00.000Z";
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone timeZone = now.getTimeZone();
String timezoneID = "IST";                // <<<<<
// Convert to System format from UTC
DateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
Date actualDate = format1.parse(date);
format1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezoneID));
String date1 = format1.format(actualDate);
String time = date1.substring(11, 16);
String timezoneValue = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezoneID).getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT);
String finalTime = time + " " + timezoneValue;
System.out.print(finalTime);
```

Comment: Using your code with the `setTimeZone` show 08:47. isnt?

Comment: My method and your method above both show 14:17 but it should be plus 5.30 hrs. that is 19:47

Comment: @SamMaul i think thats ok now, shows `19:47 IST`